# Where can users create temporary files safely?

Tags: tmp

Once `/tmp` ideally should be reserved for the system, where can a user create temporary files safely?

Comment: Anywhere the user has access to, e. g. in his home directory which is not cleaned up by any system tool.

Comment: Why not use `mktemp` and leave the details for the implementation to decide?

Comment: Why should `/tmp` ideally be reserved for the system?

Comment: *should be reserved for the system* - this is false. `/tmp` was created exactly with multi user environment in mind.

Comment: Back when I started out 30 years ago with the systems I looked after, it used to be `/var/tmp` was the place for users to store temporary files. That directory also tended to be preserved across reboots, whereas `/tmp` was wiped, especially since it was a virtual mount. That no longer seems to happen in many places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right place to create temporary files¹ is, and has always been, the directory indicated by the `TMPDIR` environment variable, with `/tmp` as a fallback. If a system has a location for temporary files other than `/tmp`, setting `TMPDIR` is how it advertises this location.

In a shell script, that's `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}`, although typically you should call the `mktemp` command and let it decide.

¹  <sub>Of course, I'm not talking about temporary files that need to be in a specific directory, for example because they'll be atomically moved into place once their content is ready.</sub>